# android how to get PNR status of a PNR no through code

Tags: android

In my application, i have an activity where one EditText and a Button are there.

I want to enter PNR no and if i press "check PNR status" button then it should give the PNR status . 
How i can do that? 
Plz give me some sample exapmle for better understanding.
Thank you

Comment: or any api is available for that? plz suggest me any way.

Answer (score 3):

I have achieved similar kind of task for my iPhone application which is not yet published. You can examine http://www.pnrstatuscheck.in to get the pnr status. They are using service from http://www.mmtstraintimings.in/pnrstatus/{yourPNRnumber}

This solve the major worry of getting pnr status information.

getRequestLine() and getEntity() can be used to make http requests from android.

Example :

```
public void postData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey i wanted to make it in iphone only. can you help me plz... how should i start and what should i do.??

Comment: you have to use NSURLRequest class to make an http request.

Comment: @user273298 : Needed your help with the API call in android. Have worked with web-services but this is totally new to me. Would be obliged if you provided some help. Thanks!